# Added data reducing accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm running into a situation where giving a neural network extra data reduces accuracy, and I can't see how that's possible.

Suppose you train a neural network - just a binary classifier - on a set of examples that have, say, 10 variables each. And it learns to classify both training and tests sets quite accurately. Then rerun with the same examples but extra variables on each example, say an extra 20 variables each. Maybe the extra variables don't give as good a signal as the original ones, but it's still getting the original variables too. Worst-case scenario, it should just take a bit more time learning to ignore the extra variables, right? On the face of it, there shouldn't be any way for the accuracy to be less?

To go through everything I can think of:

- It's the same set of records in each case.
- All the original variables are still there, just with some extra ones added.
- It's not about overfitting; the network trained with the extra data is much less accurate on both the training and test sets.
- I don't think it's about needing more time. It's been running for a long time now and showing no signs of making progress.
- I've tried with the learning rate both unchanged and reduced, same result each way.

Using TensorFlow, simple feedforward network with one hidden layer, Adam optimizer. Code is at https://github.com/russellw/tf-examples/blob/master/multilayer.py and the most important section is

```
# Inputs and outputs
X = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=(None, cols))
Y = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=None,)

# Hidden layers
n1 = 3
w1 = tf.Variable(rnd((cols, n1)), dtype=dtype)
b1 = tf.Variable(rnd(n1), dtype=dtype)
a1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(X, w1) + b1)
pr('layer 1: {}', n1)

# Output layer
no = 1
wo = tf.Variable(rnd((n1, no)), dtype=dtype)
bo = tf.Variable(rnd(no), dtype=dtype)
p = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.squeeze(tf.matmul(a1, wo)) + bo)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()

# Model
cost = tf.reduce_sum((p-Y)**2/rows)
optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(args.learning_rate).minimize(cost)
tf.global_variables_initializer().run()
```

How is it *possible* for the extra data to make the network less accurate? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out to have at least something to do with the properties of the optimizer. Though Adam worked the best of all the optimizers in one case, in a slightly different case it fails badly where Ftrl solves the problem. I don't know why Adam has this failure mode, but current solution: make optimizer a parameter, use a batch file to loop through all of them.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing between variables and (training) data. Variables are something you use to find, say weights and biases, that help the network learn from data. So by increasing variables you are increasing trainable units, which warrants more time obviously. After a certain threshold, your data might become insufficient for the network to learn/update these variables.

Extra data means simply more examples.

So in your case it seems that you've crossed that threshold (assuming you've waited for your NN learning, long enough before saying it's not learning anymore).

Comment: No, in this case by extra variables I mean extra features or attributes per example. Imagine the network is learning to recognize people from photographs. First I crop the photographs to faces only, and it learns to classify accurately. Then I present the uncropped photographs, same set of examples with extra features per example, and now it no longer learns to classify accurately. How is that possible?

Comment: @rwallace Cropped and uncropped photographs differ a lot, so your network can't correlate/apply the facial features learnt previously to new (training) images. What it tries to do is learn everything from scratch. Which is not wrong, but then you can't compare the accuracy, time (and training data) in these two cases. There can be many more features that the network is trying to learn, which you don't find obvious (say it may find colour of a shirt as a feature from training images, and then goes wrong by always predicting Blue means Bob!). It's usually better to restrict features to interest.

Comment: @rwallace contd. Eventually your network will learn from images with more data (and more noise ofcourse) but it will need more data and more resources like time. In an extreme case, increased complexity may also render some problems too difficult to attempt practically.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to know a phenomenon called curse of dimensionality. From Wikipedia, it says:

> The common theme of these problems is that when the dimensionality increases, the volume of the space increases so fast that the available data become sparse.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality